# how to read first 5 mails using Javamail API?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

how to read first 5 emails using JavaMail API?

I am able to fetch total number of mails. Not able to fetch 1st 5 emails

Comment: Please review [Ask] and [MCVE], then update your question with the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Message[] msgs = folder.getMessages(1, 5);
```

Was it really that confusing?